# Translate 'You must leave room for nature'

Tags: translation, word-meaning

I am trying to translate 'You must leave room for nature' and I am not sure how to translate the word 'room' in this context.

So far I have considered:

1. *Vi devas lasi ĉambron por naturo.* 
   (google's choice for 'room', but feels just wrong, and probably is wrong since it refers to a physical place)
2. *Vi devas lasi spacon por naturo.* 
   (which feels okay, but I can't really say why, and vortaro confuses me a bit)
3. *Vi devas lasi lokon por naturo.* 
   (which feels wrong again. Is *loko* about a specific place/location?)

Other words I have considered and dismissed are *areo*, *tereno*.

Comment: Malgranda gramatika korekto: *…devas **lasi**…*, ne ***lasu***. Kaj ankaŭ, vi forgesis la akuzativon.

Comment: So based on a comment on my answer, I need to ask: are we talking about making sure that nature has room to function, or are we talking about setting aside a literal space for nature as in - the house goes here, and we're going to leave an acre for nature over here?

Comment: Yes, the first, making sure nature has room to function whatever that function may be.  I'm struggling to make that more clear in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In English, the three nouns correspond to:

- *ĉambro* — a room (in a building)
- *spaco* — space, a space
- *loko* — a place, a position

So I think *lasi spacon* is closest to the meaning of *leave room* (without an article). *Lasi lokon* is fine but closer to *leave a place for...* (i.e. arrange for a specific location to be unoccupied for someone else's use). *To leave **a** room/place* (to go away) is *forlasi ĉambron/lokon*.

Answer (score 4):

*Lokon* or *spacon* is fine.

Note that it's *devas las**i***. Not *devas las**u***. (Edit: I see that has been corrected in the meanwhile.)

Comment: Dankon, since loko is a place and my 'nature' refers to the concept, not a specific natural process or phenomenon, I'm tending to go for spaco...